# Get value of a regex sub-subgroup

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a regex to extract links from a wiki-like page:

```
for mo in re finditer(r"\[\[([^|\]]+)(|([^\]]+))?\]\]", page):
```

(wiki links look like `[[link target]]` or `[[link target|text]]`

The matches are OK, however, I cannot find a way to get `text` from the sub-subgroup of the second part: `[[(…)(|(I need the contents of this group))?]]`

The return value of `mo.groups()` for such a link looks like this (first line is the input for this match):

```
"[[:Groups:Admins|Admins]]"
(':Groups:Admins', '|Admins', '|Admins')
```

I’m expecting the 3rd element to be `Admins` instead of `|Admins`.

I know I could simply chop the pipe character (actually that’s what I’m doing right now), but is there a `re` way to do this?

(I’m using Python 3.4.1)

Comment: an example would be better.(input along with expected output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to escape the in-between `|` symbol, so that it would match a literal `|` symbol or otherwise it would do a regex OR operation. `|` inside a character class, would loose it's special meaning and matches only the literal `|` symbol. But the unescaped  `|` symbol outside the character class would act like an [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

```
\[\[([^|\]]+)(\|([^\]]+))?\]\]
              ^
              |
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cW4qQ3/14)

```
>>> s = "[[:Groups:Admins|Admins]]"
>>> for mo in re.finditer(r"\[\[([^|\]]+)(\|([^\]]+))?\]\]", s):
        mo.groups()


(':Groups:Admins', '|Admins', 'Admins')
```

Comment: This was a lame overlook of me… thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

Put the | inside a non-capture group:

```
r"\[\[([^|\]]+)(?:\|([^\]]+))?\]\]"
```

and as Avinash points out, escape the |, the result will then be:

```
(':Groups:Admins', 'Admins')
```